# Django-Chartit 'source' must either be a QuerySet, Model or Manager

Tags: javascript, python, django, highcharts

I am using [Django-Chartit](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/) to create a chart.
Trying to follow [this](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/docs/#how-to-use) example.
my problem is that i want to use data not from a model
so i tried this code

```
data = \
    DataPool(
       series=
        [{'options': {
           'source': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]},
          'terms': [
            'month',
            'houston_temp',
            'boston_temp']}
         ])
chart = Chart(
        datasource = data,
        series_options =
          [{'options':{
              'type': 'line',
              'stacking': False},
            'terms':{
              'month': [
                'boston_temp',
                'houston_temp']
              }}],
        chart_options =
          {'title': {'text': 'Weather Data of Boston and Houston'},
           'xAxis': {'title': {'text': 'Month number'}
                     }})
```

and i got an error message

> 'source' must either be a QuerySet, Model or Manager. Got [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] of type  instead.

I dont think i can create a QuerySet from a list.
Any idea ?

Comment: Hi @yossi. Thanks about this question. At this time, I'm just in this frame of mind. How do you have solve it? Thanks.

Comment: i used highcharts javascript instead and rendered the data as a string to the javascript in the page

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on it. I also think that is a elegant solution. Also, for me, Highstock is a better solution. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Django-Chartit is really meant for making charts out of models. Notice the tag line:

```
Create charts from your Django models effortlessly
```

If there is a specific reason you can't use a model, I would look into using a separate web charts tool [such as Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/). It's pure JavaScript, so you would need to send your data to the client-side in order to make charts.

Answer (score 1):

First of all from their [docs](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/docs/apireference.html#chartit.DataPool) `terms` must be a list or dict of valid fields on the `source` which **must be** a Model, queryset or a manager.

So what kind of data do you want to use?

UPDATE: What is this list data source exactly? If it is a list containing id's
of a model you can do this to make it a queryset

```
MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=[3,1,2,5,77])
```

Comment: i would like to use just a simple list

Comment: @yossi see my update. If that doesn't suit you, better see the suggestion made by Paragon

Comment: no it is not a list if id's, it is just a simple list that has nothing to do with models.