# Custom x-Axis name from different fields in django-chartit

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I have model like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    n_1 = models.IntegerField()
    n_2 = models.IntegerField()
```

Date is unique and type is not.
I want to create chart with X-Axis labels like "Type (Date)" i.e. "FirstType (2014-10-02)", so I want to combine data from two model fields in axis label. Can you please advice me how can I do it?

Comment: Please explain reasons for minuses, I didn't find any suitable answer..

Comment: There is no evidence of any attempt to solve the problem. You have described your model but your definition does not match your description (the date field you have provided is not unique). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Date here doesn't have unique property just because it's like a prototype. In fact it has unique values, you can believe me.

Answer (score 2):

It is not required to pass the model objects directly to chartit. You can transform them into dicts which then have the appropriate values:

```
data = [
    {'label': "{0} ({1})".format(o.date, o.type), 'value': o.n_1}
    for o in MyModel.objects.all()
]
```

See [the documentation](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/docs/apireference.html#chart) for the library you have chosen to use for more information.

Comment: It doesn't work. My code is following:
    ds = DataPool(
      series= [
       {'options':{
          'source': [{'n_1': o.n_1, 'n_2': o.n_2, 'datetype': o.date} for o in MyModel.objects.all()]
          },
        'terms': .....}])
            
And it raises error "'source' must either be a QuerySet, Model or Manager" because it's required(!) to pass model objects to chartit. It was mentioned in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471465/django-chartit-source-must-either-be-a-queryset-model-or-manager. This library requires model objects. 

The same mentioned in documentation